# What's the difference between Slope and Magnitude of a line segment? Is there any?

Tags: geometry, terminology

Is there any difference between Slope and Magnitude? or are they the same thing. Even a slightly different use case would be helpful.

Comment: I would imagine that the Magnitude of a line segment was simply its length.  Nothing to do with slope.

Comment: ah okay, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Those two are completely different things:

Magnitude refers just to length.

Given two coordinate axes, the slope of a segment is the number of units you go up the y-axis for every unit you go right in the x-axis.

For instance, in 2D space, the segment joining the points $(0,0)$ and $(2,4)$ has slope $2$ and magnitude $\sqrt{20}$.

A big "difference" I can see between the two is that length is a property "intrinsic" to the segment, while slope depends on coordinates. For example, if you rotate a segment around, its slope will change, but its length will stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways (*coordinate systems*) to locate a point in the plane:

**Rectangular (a.k.a. Cartesian) coordinates:** $(x, y)$ corresponds to moving over $x$ units and up $y$ units. The lines of constant $x$-coordinate are vertical and the lines of constant $y$-coordinate are horizontal. Together they produce a rectangular grid.

**Polar coordinates:** $(r, \theta)$ corresponds to moving out *radially* $r$ units and in a direction given by angle $\theta$. The lines of constant $r$-coordinate are concentric circles, and the lines of constant $\theta$-coordinate are radial rays. Together they produce a "dartboard" grid.

Trigonometry describes the correspondence between these two coordinate systems:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x &= r \cos \theta \\
y &= r \sin \theta
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

The **magnitude** of the segment from the origin to a point is the radial distance $r$, where
$$
r^2 = x^2 + y^2
$$
and the **slope** of the segment from the origin to a point corresponds with the angle:
$$
m = \frac{y}{x} = \tan \theta.
$$
Caveat: when $x=0$ (or equivalently, when $\theta$ is an odd multiple of the right angle), the slope is not defined.